# Simple generate button with html and javascript and save after finish

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to generate a simple button by HTML and JavaScript. Unfortunately, I don't know how to it with JavaScript to catch to value from input range HTML to apply for button. How could I use JavaScript to catch value from HTML range?
this is my html code:

```
<form name='frm'>
<div id="div">
    <label>
        Width:
        <input type="text" id="MyText"/>
        <input type="range" id="MyRange" oninput="myfunc()"/>
    </label><br/>
    <label>
        Height:
        <input type="text" id="height"/>
        <input type="range" id="heights" oninput="myfunc()"/><br/>
    </label><br/>
    <label>
        Background:
        <input type="text" id="bdg"/>
        <input type="color" id="background"/>
       <!--/* <input type="range"/>
        <input type="imge" name="imge"/>*/-->
    </label><br/>
    <label>
        Radius:
        <input type="text" name="rad" id="Radius"/>
        <input type="range" name="rad" id="Rd"/><br/>
    </label><br/>
    <label>
        Margin:
        <input type="text" name="margin" id="margin"/><br/>
    </label><br/>
    <label>
        Padding:
        <input type="text" name="padding" id="padding"/><br/>
    </label><br/>
    <label>
        Box-shadow:
        <input type="text" name="shadow" id="shadow"/><br/>
    </label><br/>
</div>
<div id="div">
    <label>
        Color:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="col" id="color"/>
        <input type="color" id="colors"/><br/>
    </label>
    <label>
        Border-width:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="bdwidths" id="bw"/>
        <input type="range" id="bdw"/><br/>
    </label>
    <label>
        Border-style:<br/>
        <input type="number" name="bdstyle" id="bdstyle"/><br/>
    </label>
    <label>
        Border-color:<br/>
        <input type="number" name="bdcol" id="bdcolor"/>
        <input type="color" id="color"/><br/>
    </label>
    <label>
        Text-align:<br/>
        <input type="number" name="aligns" id="ta"/><br/>
    </label> 
    <label>
        Font-size:<br/>
        <input type="number" name="font" id="font"/>
        <input type="range" id="font-size"/><br/><br/>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="button" value="save change" onclick="save()"/>
    </label>
</div>
</form>
```

My Button

Comment: Why do you have two inputs with the same name?

Comment: I didn't understand your question properly. do you want your code to generate a <button> with width and height set in the two input fields by the user??

Comment: As Barmar has pointed out, you can give elements ID's so you can access them or you can use `document.frm['widths'].value` you will need to keep the names unique. Personally I would give the elements ID's. I'm just posting this as a second solution. If you don't keep the elements names unique you can access them using `document.frm['widths'][0].value` - `document.frm['widths'][1].value` The first element with will use `[0]` and the second will use `[1]`. I'm sure you can work out how that increments.

Comment: @Barmar Because I want to show the value of range on this input or I can type value to the input text.

Comment: @RohitKumar Yes, I do. I want the button generate width, height automatically  when I change to range or type the value in the input text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger the javascript function you need to listen for changes/events.

This is using the `oninput` attribute. This will trigger/call the javascript function `myfunc` each time the range has a new input.

This is now using id attributes, not name attributes.

> `document.getElementById('')` Is used to target the element
>   `document.getElementById('').value` is used to target the elements value.

```js
function myfunc(){
//Assign a variable to the MyRange element.
 var MyVariable= document.getElementById('MyRange');
//Target the MyText input and change the value to the value of MyVariable.
 document.getElementById('MyText').value=MyVariable.value+'px';
//Target MyBtn's style - width
document.getElementById('MyBtn').style.width=MyRange.value+'px';
}
```

```html
Width:<input type="text" id="MyText"/><br/>
<input type="range" id="MyRange" oninput="myfunc()"/>
<button id="MyBtn">My Button</button>
```

If you don't understand any of the source code please leave a comment below and I will explain it line by line for you so you understand how this works. It's better to understand how something works rather than copy/paste and hope for the best.

> Javascript should be placed inside of script tags
>
> `<script type="text/javascript">
>   //Place Javascript Here....
>   </script>`

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank for your help but when change place of range, it will check the pixel and apply it to width of button(increase button width).

Comment: @PherumChheang You want the range to change the width of the button? Your question is "how to catch the value of the range" this example shows how to do that. I'm not sure what it is you're wanting with the button. Can you be more clear please? I will edit the answer as your question becomes more clear to what you wish to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I want the range to change the width of the button. but I don't know how to do it with JavaScript to complete it. And I put the value input text to in px to apply the button

Comment: Yes, it works well with this. But if I have only input type text what should I do. Padding:
   <input type="text" name="padding" id="padding"/><br/>

Comment: @PherumChheang What do you mean if you input text? Your question is how to get the range and display it in the input text box, then you wanted it to change the width of the button. If you wish the expand your question can you give full details on what you wish to achieve. This will save multiple edits on answers. If this answers your question, marking it would be appreciated too.

Comment: @PherumChheang Can you update your question description and give full details what you wish to achieve please? Once I fully understand what you expect the changes (your update) to do I will edit my question the best I can. I have to go to work now so sorry for any late reply.

Answer (score 0):

Give the element an ID so you can access it:

```
<input type="range" id="widthrange" name="widths"/>
```

Then in your Javascript, you can do:

```
var width = document.getElementById("widthrange").value;
```